# SQL :Fill null date and null value in the rol

Tags: sql, presto

I have table like this

```
user |    date    | Balance| 
AAA  | 2019-10-25 | 100    | 
AAA  | 2019-10-23 | 125    | 
AAA  | 2019-10-22 | 150    | 
AAA  | 2019-10-20 | 100    |
```

I want to fill missing date and value on that day with previous date & value.
and fill the first row(and other day that missing) with current date with previous value too.

```
  user |    date    | Balance| 
**AAA  | 2019-10-27 | 100    |** 
**AAA  | 2019-10-26 | 100    |**
  AAA  | 2019-10-25 | 100    |
**AAA  | 2019-10-24 | 125    |** 
  AAA  | 2019-10-23 | 125    | 
  AAA  | 2019-10-22 | 150    |
**AAA  | 2019-10-21 | 100    |** 
  AAA  | 2019-10-20 | 100    |
```

Answer (score 1):

The key here is generating the dates:

```
  select u.dte
  from (values (sequence(cast('2019-10-20' as date),
                         cast('2019-10-27' as date),
                         interval '1' day
                        )
               )
       ) v(date_array) cross join
       unnest(v.date_array) u(dte)
```

Then, you can use this information to fill in the values:

```
with dates as (
      select u.dte
      from (values (sequence(cast('2019-10-20' as date),
                             cast('2019-10-27' as date),
                             interval '1' day
                            )
                   )
           ) v(date_array) cross join
           unnest(v.date_array) u(dte)
      )
select user, dte,
       max(balance) over (partition by user, grp) as balance
from (select d.dte, u.user, t.balance,
             count(t.user) over (partition by u.user order by d.dte) as grp
      from dates d cross join
           (select distinct user from t) u left join
           t
           on t.date = d.dte and t.user = u.user
     ) du
order by user, dte;
```

The final query is implementing `lag(ignore nulls)`.  What it does is assign a grouping based on the presence of a record in your data -- that is what the `count(t.user) over ()` is doing.  The outer `select` then spreads this value over the entire group.

EDIT:

According to Piotr's comment:

```
select user, dte,
       coalesce(balance,
                lag(balance) ignore nulls over (partition by user, grp)
               ) as balance
from dates d cross join
     (select distinct user from t) u left join
     t
     on t.date = d.dte and t.user = u.user
order by user, dte;
```

Comment: _The final query is implementing lag(ignore nulls)._ -- Presto supports `lag(..) IGNORE NULLS` directly since Presto 319 (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-319.html).

Comment: do you need to include `IGNORE NULLS` after `lag(balance)`?